# Cannot access next.js session when requesting from client

Tags: next.js

I'm having trouble setting up an RBAC route in my next.js app.

I have a basic server component:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { getUserPackages } from "~/server/api/user-packages";

const MyCoursesPage = async () => {
  const packages = await getUserPackages();

  if (packages.error) {
    return <div>failed to load, no session</div>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="flex h-screen text-red-500">
      <h1>My Courses</h1>
      <div className="flex flex-col ">
        {packages.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div key={item.id} className="mb-2">
              <Link href={`/package/${item.id}`}>{item.title}</Link>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyCoursesPage;
```

It uses the following method:

```
export const getUserPackages = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `${process.env.BASE_URL || "http://localhost:3000"}/api/user-packages`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      credentials: "include",
    }
  );

  const packages = await response.json();
  return packages;
};
```

which makes a call toward this endpoint:

```
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);

  console.log("Server side session", session);

  if (session?.user) {
    const userPackages = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: session?.user.id,
      },
      select: {
        packages: true,
      },
    });

    res.status(200).json(userPackages);
    return;
  } else {
    console.log("Session", JSON.stringify(session, null, 2));
    res.status(401).json({ error: "Not authenticated" });
    return;
  }
}
```

When fetching my data directly from the browser (navigating to localhost:3000/api/user-packages), I can see in my console that I do have a session, and a list of packages is returned.

But when I fetch it from within the app by going to `localhost:3000/my-courses`, the session is gone from the endpoint, and therefore no data is returned.

Am I missing something? I thought adding "credentials: true" to my request would take care of the headers.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: yup, with the new version, when using JWT strategy, yu don't have a session ballback, as described here : https://authjs.dev/guides/upgrade-to-v5#authenticating-server-side